# My Application has silently crashed when an activity in another application crashes

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity in my application which is accessing an activity from some other application for some task to be done(This may be an application downloaded form the play store app), i start the activity with the following code in my button click listener,

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.myapp.package", "com.myapp.package.className"));
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startActivity(i);
```

If The other application has some crash in it, and does something wrong and it crashes.

and as a result my application is silently killed by the Activity manager, please find below the log,

```
02-26 17:39:31.469   281   532 I ActivityManager: START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.example.dummy.mydummyapp2.DummyApp2 (has extras) u=0} from pid 8487
02-26 17:39:31.469   281   532 W WindowManager: Failure taking screenshot for (230x143) to layer 22000
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dummy.mydummyapp2/com.example.dummy.mydummyapp2.DummyApp2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.example.dummy.mydummyapp2.DummyProvider.search(DummyProvider.java:136)
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.example.dummy.mydummyapp2.DummyApp2.onCreate(DummyApp2.java:115)
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
02-26 17:39:31.541 16816 16816 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
.
.
02-26 17:39:31.553   281 24382 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.dummy.mydummyapp2/.DummyApp2
02-26 17:39:31.553   281 24382 W WindowManager: Failure taking screenshot for (230x143) to layer 22015
*****02-26 17:39:31.553   281 24382 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.dummy.mydummyapp1/.activities.DummyApp1*****
02-26 17:39:32.053   281   294 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{a7082df0 com.example.dummy.mydummyapp2/.DummyApp2}
02-26 17:39:32.437   281   281 I ActivityManager: No longer want com.google.android.partnersetup (pid 31498): hidden #16
*02-26 17:39:42.437   281   294 W ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{a7082df0 com.example.dummy.mydummyapp2/.DummyApp2}*
02-26 17:40:16.265   281 24383 I ActivityManager: Process com.example.dummy.mydummyapp2 (pid 16816) has died.
02-26 17:44:10.305   281   444 W ThrottleService: unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
```

I am not worried about the crash in the dummyapp2, i am worried with only why my app is crashed because of the crash in some other application.

I have tried with different flags in the intent, as below,

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

and

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

but with no result.

Is this the normal behavior of android,
if my applications starts an activity from other application and the other application crashes my app also crashes???????

Please Somebody clarify on, i am stuck.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If other activity something specific,(I used barcode reader activity like that for example) you could use startActivityForResult,

I used something like that and worked for me, I hope it works for you too,

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 23);
```

and on ActivityResult,

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 23) {
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             // use result values
         final String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
         final String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
             //dosmthng
       }
    }
}
```

do something with returning intent.

In my application if barcodereader application crushes my application still works.

Answer (score 0):

Please try surrounding the call to other activity / application in `try{}` `catch{}` block, the error log shows a `NullPointerException`, you can control the crash in this way.